# no module named error after installing with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to import matplotlib library, which I have installed via cmd: pip install matplotlib. And it installed successfully. But when I try to import matplotlib in jupyter lab, it gives me an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9738723f2bbd> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib as plt
      2 from matplotlib import pyplot as pllt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I checked both my python files and the installed matplotlib are in the same directory. Any ideas whats's wrong?

Comment: You are not using the same version of Python in your Jupyter notebook as you used to install `matplotlib`. Fix that.

Comment: I uninstalled matplotlib and reinstalled via cmd but it still prints no module

Comment: From the command line, run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)`, then put the same code (minus the `python -c` part) in your Jupyter notebook and run it. What are the outputs?

Comment: in cmd i get this: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: meanwhile in jupyter i got this 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Well there you go. You seem to have (at least) 2 different Python installations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236330/discussion-between-anna-abrahamyan-and-mattdmo).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happens that pip is installing the module for older python versions. Try to reinstall using pip3

Edit: as pointed out by MattDMo, on Windows they are both installed in the same folder. However, leaving this answer as this might be an issue  in Linux.

Comment: `pip` is an alias for `pip3`. On Windows, they are both installed in the same folder, along with `pip3.9` in this case.